# How many employees are there in the office

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

> In an office, $37$ people like $X$ drink, $32$ people like $Y$ drink and $41$ people like $Z$ drink. Also, $5$ employees like all the types of drinks and $15$ people like at least two types of drinks. If each of the employees like at least one type of drink , then how many employees are there in the office?

Question says that $15$ people like at least two types of drinks. Mathematically does it mean

$n(X \cap Y)+n(Y \cap Z)+n(Z \cap X)+n(X \cap Y \cap Z)=15$?

Comment: If by $n(X\cap Y)$ you mean "the number of people who prefer $X$ and $Y$, but _not_ $Z$", then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Your expression:
$$n(X \cap Y)+n(Y \cap Z)+n(Z \cap X)+n(X \cap Y \cap Z)=15$$

counts the three-way intersection a total of $4$ times. Instead you need to remove it twice from the total of the three two-way intersections:
$$n(X \cap Y)+n(Y \cap Z)+n(Z \cap X)-2\times n(X \cap Y \cap Z)=15$$